flutter audio chat with flutter firebase chat ui
i what to add audio in to chat like author app social media
now i have setup flutter firebase chat Ui done but i just want to add audio like author app
i have see some question in stack overflow to like they provide answer
but i do not understand it you can tell me step by step to setup audio in flutter chat Ui?
audioMessageBuilder: (types.AudioMessage audioMessage,
              {required int messageWidth}) {
            final isMine = audioMessage.author.id == _myUser.id;
            return VoiceMessageView(
              backgroundColor: isMine ? primaryColor : secondaryColor,
              controller: VoiceController(
                audioSrc: audioMessage.uri,
                maxDuration: audioMessage.duration,
                onComplete: () {},
                onPause: () {},
                onPlaying: () {},
                isFile: false,
              ),
            );
          }

